# In Neon Genesis Evangelion, who/what is Rei Ayanami?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, neon-genesis-evangelion, end-of-evangelion

In *Neon Genesis Evangelion*, the character of Rei Ayanami was consistently kept shrouded in mystery. Even after watching *End of Evangelion*, I still cannot understand who she is, or more specifically, *what* she is.

I might have missed a lot of details, so here are some things that I can't piece together:

- Commander Ikari says she was "an acquaintance's child" (you can't possibly be more vague than that). Ritsuko's mother said she looked like Yui.
- People see hallucinations of her, mostly at the moment of death. Shinji even randomly sees a vision of her at the beginning of ep. 1, for some reason.
- In *End of Evangelion* she somehow has superpowers. This confused me the most, as she has never shown any signs of magical powers before.
- Kawaru says she is the soul of Lillith, or something like that.

So I can't piece together any of these. How was she born? Why does she look like Yui? Why does she have god-like abilities, and how is she "the soul of Lillith"? If she did have god-like powers all along, why didn't she display them before? Why does she even pilot an eva if she can generate abnormally strong AT fields?

In other words, **what** is she exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Rei is a clone of Yui with Liliths soul (see the white body in the basement) inside of her thus why she looks like Yui. How they put the soul into a body not explained to my knowledge

Lilith is progenitor of humanity and is linked with humanity though never directly stated we can assume/theorize that this is why people see hallucinations of her as she is the soul of the sealed/defunct diety

She did not have God like powers all along, it was only when the Lilith based Evangelion merged with Adam based life form that awakened and revived Lilith thus giving Rei (the soul)god power as Adam and Lilith merged and when she begins appearing to turn everyone into tang

As to why she pilots the Eva I can only guess because someone needs to. If Adam reaches Lilith everything is over so use any available resource

Beginning of the show she is a clone with thesoul of a dead/de-powered god/deity. End of the show she is a god with original Yui soul(which was in Unit 01)/Rei (Liliths soul).